# Trying to show an input from html using javascript

Tags: javascript

We were asked to write a javascript code that shows the input by clicking the button of a html file.
I managed to do it as follows:

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("in1").value;
  document.getElementById("btn1").alert(x);
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1">
  <input id="in1" type="text" name="" value="" />
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="ok" />
</form>
```

but clicking on the button doesn't show me anything What is the problem?(I get the input from in1 and clicking on button 1. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert` is a `window` function. You should either call `alert(x)` directly or call `window.alert(x)`:

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("in1").value;
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1">
  <input id="in1" type="text" name="" value="" />
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="ok" />
</form>
```

Comment: It works her but when I get it to w3 school editor or on php storm editor the webpage doesn't show anything Am I mssing something?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eventListener for this

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="frm1">
        <input id="in1" type="text" name="" value="" />
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="ok" />
    </form>
    
    <script>
    document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', function(){
        var x=document.getElementById("in1").value;
        alert(x);
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6:

```js
btn1.onclick = () => alert(in1.value);
```

```html
<form id="frm1">
  <input id="in1" type="text" name="" value="" />
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="ok" />
</form>
```